# Reading CSV files with Chinese Characters

Tags: r, utf-8, windows-7, locale

There are a number of StackOverflow posts about opening CSV files containing (UTF-8 encoded) Chinese characters into R, in Windows. None of the answers I've found seem to work completely.

If I `read.csv` with `encoding="UTF-8"`, then the Chinese characters are shown encoded (`<U+XXXX>`, which I've manually verified are at least correct). However, if I interrogate the data frame to get just one row or a specific cell from a row, then it's printed properly.

One post suggested this is due to strings being typed as factors. However, setting `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` had no effect.

Other posts say the locale must be set correctly. My system locale is apparently `English_United Kingdom.1252`; a Windows code page looks decidedly non-Unicode friendly! If I try to change it to any of `en.UTF-8`, `en_GB.UTF-8` or `en_US.UTF-8` (or even `UTF-8` or `Unicode`), I get an error saying that my OS cannot honour the request.

If I try `Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale="Chinese")`, the locale *does* change (albeit to another Windows code page; still no Unicode) but then the CSV files can't be parsed. That said, if I read the files in the English locale and then switch to Chinese afterwards, the data frame is printed out correctly in the console. However, this is cludgy and, regardless, `View(myData)` now shows [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) rather than the encoded Unicode code points.

Is there any way to just make it all work? That is, correct Chinese characters are echoed from the data frame to the console *and* `View` works, without having to perform secret handshakes when reading the data?

My gut feeling is that the problem is the locale: It should be set to a UTF-8 locale and then everything should [might] just work. However, I don't know how to do that...

Comment: To add evidence to my hypothesis: On my work computer (OS X), loading a CSV with Chinese text just works, both in the console and in `View`, how I would expect, with no messing around. The locale there is `en_GB.UTF-8`... Is it possible to change to a UTF-8 locale in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The UTF notation is good and it means your characters were read in property. The issue is on R's side with printing to console, which shouldn't be a big problem unless you are copying and pasting output. Writing out is a bit tricky: you want to open a UTF-8 file connection, then write to that file.